# Remote debugging with visual studio and WinDbg server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, windbg, native

Is it possible to use WinDBG as a server (instead of Visual Studio Remote Debugger) and connect to it using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this is not possible.  WinDbg and Visual Studio use different protocols for remote debugging that are not compatible.

I'm more familiar with Visual Studio's protocol which is RPC + COM based.  I'm less familiar with WinDbg's but I believe it is lower protocol.  Usually all you need to do is just open a TCP port for WinDbg.

Comment: I've read somewhere that they are using the same debugging engine. If i can connect with WinDBG to a WinDBG server then I assume that I can use Visual Studio to do the same thing.

Comment: @Bogdan, unfortunately the information you heard is incorrect.  WinDbg and VS use very different debugging engines (100% different code bases).  They do use the same underlying APIs and it is possible to host certain WinDbg plugins inside of Visual Studio but that's far as it goes (at least that I'm aware of).